# HP zbook firefly 14 g7 driver problems

Tags: drivers, 20.04, fan

I recently installed ubuntu (dual boot along with Windows 10) on my new HP zbook firefly 14 g7 laptop and I am facing the following problems:

- In additional drivers, there is an "Intel Corporation: Unknown" option that is using hardware support for a different model

[image]

- Fan starts running loudly without doing anything demanding in particular
- Scrolling in Firefox is very laggy, which is very unusual for such a powerful computer

Any ideas on what might be going wrong or what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm there is an issue with the hybrid graphics. I tried various systems (Ubuntu 20.04, 21.10, Debian 11). When any app tries to access the NVIDIA GPU (Quadro P520 GP108) the system becomes unresponsive, and fan starts. A message is displayed in the console, stating that the kernel is tainted (which is true, by the NVIDIA module).

`lspci -d 10de: -nnv` lists the GPU at 6c:0. A call to `nvidia-smi` displays the GPU, but lags (2 sec to respond). A call to `clinfo` just hangs.

I have not found any solution except, for the time being, to only use the Intel integrated GPU. I thus suggest to stay with the default `nouveau` driver. This is the default choice with Debian. Ubuntu installs the NVIDIA driver automatically.